# Qt plugin for Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, qt

I have installed PyDev and want to start with GUI apps. Heard about Qt but how to integrate it with PyDev? Is there any Python IDE that comes bundled with Qt or other GUI frameworks and also Visual Studio like ToolBox to add controls on the Form?

I don't want to go with IronPython.

Comment: MonkeyStudio is a good IDE for developing PyQt application.it comes with Qt Designer inbuilt with itself so you don't have to open Qt Designer seperately.
you can directly program in python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write Qt applications using Python, you need [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). To integrate Python, PyQt, PyDev, and Eclipse, you need to do some installation work and set things up correctly. You should find a reasonable starting point in this blog article: [Setting up IDE and creating a cross platform Qt Python GUI application](http://popdevelop.com/2010/04/setting-up-ide-and-creating-a-cross-platform-qt-python-gui-application/). This doesn't allow you to design your Qt UI by dragging and dropping controls. To get that, you could use Qt Designer to "draw" your UI, and then use some tools that come with PyQt to convert the saved design to Python code. This you can then edit and interface with in Eclipse. There are articles on that [here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~afedosov/qttut/), [here](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Creating_GUI_Applications_with_PyQt_and_Qt_Designer), and [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial).

There are also other IDEs that you may want to check out:

- Qt Creator
- [The Eric Python IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/)
- [Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/pyqt)
- [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide)
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) (for KDE apps, which use Qt)
- and many more.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472021/what-ide-is-good-for-developing-pyqt-apps

(Apologies for not providing links to Qt Designer and Qt Creator – I couldn't find canonical ones. Check out [qt.nokia.com](http://qt.nokia.com/) and find them there if you want.)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there is a LGPL alternative to the PyQT, namely PySide: http://www.pyside.org/

Comment: At the moment, I found that only http://monkeystudio.org that provide seamless integration with Qt Designer. It support Python. It haven't been able to automatically connect a widget signal to slot, but yeah, I think this is the best we have so far..